# How to extract a column value from a command output in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I am trying to write a shell script where I want to kill a list of processes given by `fuser` command.

[image]

The output of `fuser` is given. I want to kill the pids listed

```
kill -9 157909 1504107 1504111 1504112 2690311 3206490
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Use `awk`. But notice that the column number depends on whether the line begins with a port number or whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    -k, --kill
>          Kill processes accessing the file.  Unless changed with -SIGNAL,
>          SIGKILL is sent.  An fuser process never kills itself,  but  may
>          kill  other  fuser  processes.   The  effective  user  ID of the
>          process executing fuser is  set  to  its  real  user  ID  before
>          attempting to kill.
> ```

`fuser -k` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

ps -u beadm | awk '{print $2}' | while read line; do kill -9 $line; done